# Automatically updating chatbox

Tags: php, javascript

So i'm working on a javascript/php chatbox. Everything works except for it updating the contents of my div (this works once, but after that it doesn't keep updating it when a new message has been put into the database). Here is my code:

Javascript part:

```
   <script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 

        setInterval(function () {

            var arrayOfObjects = <?print_r(getChatArray());?>;
            var chat = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
                var object = arrayOfObjects[i];

                chat += "["+object.date+"]"+object.op+": " + object.msg + "</br>";
            }
            $('#chat').html(chat);

        }, 10);
    </script>
```

Php part:

```
<?php
function getChatArray() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id DESC"); 
    $to_encode = array();

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $size = 0;
        if($count > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              $to_encode[$size]['id'] = $row['id'];
              $to_encode[$size]['msg'] = $row['msg'];
              $to_encode[$size]['op'] = $row['op'];
              $to_encode[$size]['date'] = $row['date'];
              $size += 1;
            } 

        } else {
            return "None";
        }

return json_encode($to_encode);
}
?>
```

Any ideas as to why it isn't continually updating it?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, there are quite a few bad practices in your code too.

Comment: I think you miss the difference between client and server side

Comment: I've only just started learning js so I don't expect my code to have good practices straight off the bat.

Comment: If you absolutely need to have that `SELECT` statement there, I'd change it to `SELECT id, msg, op, date FROM shouts ORDER BY DESC` so you only get the fields you need an not a large result set, or even `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; SELECT id, msg, op, date FROM shouts ORDER BY DESC; COMMIT;` which would make it a little faster.. however, I agree with @BenM

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe does it matter though, I'm using all the fields in my database.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer Yes it matters. Mentioning each required fields will have performance advantage over `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 4):

Because every 10 milliseconds your JS is parsing the original chat room contents, you're not fetching any new contents. You'll need to implement an ajax call, and I'd highly recommend changing that setInterval to a recursive setTimeout with a more realistic delay of say 500ms so you don't kill the client.

Instead of this:

```
setInterval(function() {

    var arrayOfObjects = <?print_r(getChatArray());?>;
    ...
```

You would use something like this:

```
(function updateChat(){

    var arrayOfObjects, 
        chat, 
        max,
        _object,
        i = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url : '/getChatArray.php', // php echoes the json
        success: function(arrayOfObjects){
            for (max = arrayOfObjects.length; i < max; i++) {
                _object = arrayOfObjects[i];
                chat += "["+_object.date+"]"+_object.op+": " + _object.msg + "</br>";
            }
            $('#chat').html(chat);
            setTimeout(updateChat, 500);
        }
    });
}());
```

Obviously you would populate that ajax handler to your needs, add some more params like dataType, etc, and some error handling.

Comment: Sorry could you give me and example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your database contents will only be output to the page on initial navigation to it.
This code:

```
var arrayOfObjects = <?print_r(getChatArray());?>;
```

Will only output the contents of getChatArray()'s return when PHP renders the page. So the script can only see one state of that functions return at the time of rendering.

You need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to retrieve the content from your database asynchronously.

I suggest you:

1. Create a PHP script which outputs your data in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format
2. Use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), specifically the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function to retrieve that script's output
3. Do what you want to do with that data.